# Many conditions in MySQL query cause crash?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, mysql-connector

I am writing in Visual C++ using MySQL C Connector.

When I StringCchPrintf this query and execute and get results then it's OK.

```
SELECT orders.id, 
orders.get_date, 
orders.work_date, 
cars.car_num, 
cars.car_mark, 
customers.surname, 
customers.name, 
customers.telephone, 
workers.login, 
orders.paid, 
orders.paid_dead_line 
FROM `orders`, `cars`, `customers`, `workers` 
WHERE cars.customer_id = customers.id AND 
orders.car_id = cars.id AND 
orders.customer_id = customers.id AND 
orders.worker_id = workers.id AND 
DATE(get_date) LIKE DATE('%d-%d-%d') 
ORDER BY get_date ASC;
```

When I StringCchPrintf the query below - program is not calling free functions[1] and when I push the button again my application crashes.

```
SELECT orders.id, 
orders.get_date, 
orders.work_date, 
cars.car_num, 
cars.car_mark, 
customers.surname, 
customers.name, 
customers.telephone, 
workers.login, 
orders.paid, 
orders.paid_dead_line 
FROM `orders`, `cars`, `customers`, `workers`  
WHERE orders.paid IN ('0', '2', '3') AND //1 == paid
cars.customer_id = customers.id AND 
orders.car_id = cars.id AND 
orders.customer_id = customers.id AND 
orders.worker_id = workers.id
ORDER BY get_date ASC;
```

[1] I put MessageBox after `while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))` and the messagebox is not showing, so cleaning functions are not called and on second button push program crashes. Getting data from database and showing is in separated void function.

My Questions:

**Bad query syntax can crash program?**

**Maybe program is going out of void function before cleaning (strange)?**

Regards, David

Comment: How to get more info about crash? I have only "Program has stopped working...". How to catch the exception in C/C++ & WinAPI? GetLastError returns 0. I can't debug...

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `AND` on the last line of your WHERE clause.  Change this line:

```
orders.worker_id = workers.id AND
```

To this:

```
orders.worker_id = workers.id
```

Comment: Mistake in translating names from polish to english. It's not the reason of crash.